# Adding "search for" cell at the end of search view results like Instagram

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a search filtering through an array, which works well. However, I want to add an extra cell at the end that basically says "search for %@" where %@ is the search query. When this cell is clicked, it will load a new table view from a php query.

From what I understand I'm probably going to new 2 prototype cells, with one segueing into the new table view and the other into a view controller for results.

However, every time I try anything I'm met with a mess of exceptions. Can someone provide guidance?

Right now my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [filteredPeople objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [followers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: and what are the exceptions you receive?

Comment: Also show your other data source methods

Comment: Are you also updating the - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section method to account for the manually added extra row?